# calculating overlap percentage knowing the percentage of two population independently?

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

Assume we have a population of patients. We know that a patient might have disease A or disease B or both A&B and some might not have any.

We know that 40% of the population have A and 25% have B.  These percentages may contain patients which have both A&B. Using this information is there a way to calculate the number or the probability of the patients which have both A&B?

Comment: No.  Say you had exactly $100$ people.  It might be that the first $40$ have $A$ and the last $25$ have $B$, in which case the answer is $0$.  It also might happen that the first $40$ have $A$ and the first $25$ have $B$ in which case the answer is $25$.

Comment: @lulu what if we wanted to calculate the probability? like this https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/50269/union-of-two-independent-probabilistic-event

Comment: For discrete sets, there is no real difference between counting and probability.  My examples show that the probability $P(A\cap B)$ is simply not determined by $P(A),P(B)$.  In the example you link to, Independence is assumed.  In that case one has $P(A\cap B)=P(A)\times P(B)$ by definition.  But independence is a very strong assumption.